# 1-parameter group of diffeomorphisms with vector field without compact support

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let M be smooth manifold $(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$, let vector field on it be the stanadard $\frac{d}{dt}$ prove this vector field does not generate the 1-parameter group of diffeomorphisms.

The solution for the  equation:$\frac{dx}{dt} = 1$, is given as $F(t,\bar{x}) = t + \bar{x}$ why it can't be the 1-parameter group of diffeomorphism?(that is diffeomorphic + flow axiom)

Comment: What is exactly your definition of one parameter group?
Here, $\{F_t\}$ does not form a strict group because for example, $F_1$ is not defined. But it is a local group as it has the property $F(t,F(t',x)) = F(t+t',x)$ where this makes sense.

Comment: I mean here the global flow $F:\mathbb{R}\times M \to M$.that for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$ it's a diffeomorphism. In the statement you provide has shown $F_1$ is not defined.but I what bit confused

Comment: In your example, the manifold $M$ is just $(0,1)$, and $F$ is then defined on $\{(t,x)\in \mathbb{R}\times(0,1),~|~ 0 < t+x < 1\}$. $F$ is not defined on $\mathbb{R}\times M$.

Comment: I was originally to show the statement "every compact supported smooth vector field on a smooth manifold generate global flow"  do you have other  counterexample for the non compact  vector field. I think compact is used to provide a "bound"?Ok I got it,compact is used to prevent the flow outside the manifold as time goes to infity

Comment: Here, $M$ is not compact, and this flow is a counter example. Another counter example is $M = (0,1)\times \mathbb{R}$ and $X_p = (1,0)$ (this is the same example with one more coordinate). Moreover, the result you are stating is true for closed (= compact, boundaryless) manifold. There are counter examples in the compact case with boundary.

Comment: is there some example for $M = \mathbb{R}$ that possible to let $F_t$ may goes to infity as some fixed $t$

Comment: Just take a smooth bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ and transport the counter-example above on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DIdier_  hi as the $M = \mathbb{R}$ then the flow domain is given by $\{(t,x)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},~|~ -\infty < t+x < \infty\}$ with is global domain ?there is another question what's the difference between the $M = (0,1)\times \mathbb{R}$ and $M = (0,1)$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116525/discussion-between-didier-and-yi-li).